# Scrolling is not smooth for android app

Tags: android, gridview

I made a gallery by referencing this site http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

The issue I am facing is when i scroll down the scrolling is not smooth.

Have not done any custom modification, all the code is same as the code in above link.

Is their a problem with the code in GridViewAdapter class?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because these blocking the UI thread.

You need make it background (other thread) some of the tasks that you are using to retrieve your bitmap.

I recomend you use a library like picasso or other.

**Piccaso**

```
String photoPath= "/android_asset/DvpvklR.png";    
Picasso.with(context).load("file://"+ photoPath).into(imageView);
```

Your class GridViewImageAdapter in your method getView!

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file://"+ _filePaths.get(position))
.into(imageView);
```

removes code that does not need.

More about Piccaso http://square.github.io/picasso/

**Note** remember import the library.